# Laravel object properties serialization

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, serialization

I have a user model that returns these kind of data

```php
$user = User::all();

return response->json($user);

// output
[
  {
    "username":"someuser",
    "email":"user@email.com",
    "created_at":"some_timestamp",
    "updated_at":"some_timestamp"
  }
]
```

I want to serialize the properties from snake case (used in database column name) to camel case until it look some kind of these bellow

```php
$user = User::all();

return response->json($user);

// output
[
  {
    "username":"someuser",
    "email":"user@email.com",
    "createdAt":"some_timestamp",
    "updatedAt":"some_timestamp"
  }
]
```

I was looking in the Eloquent documentation but seems not to found anything for this. I'm thinking of writing my own utility to achieve what I want but before that, I think I'm gonna ask you guys for a lib or some kind of solution beforehand. Thanks

Comment: Create an [API resource](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources) ? And/or maybe use [Str::camel()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-camel-case)?

Comment: I don't think creating API resource is what I'm looking for @brombeer but it's a nice idea to create a getter like `$user->toCustomArray()` just like shown in the docs but I have to create it for every single model. Or may be I can create a static function and use the `Str::camel()` to replace all the key and then I can just call `Serializer::serialize($user)`. I think I prefer the second idea. Thanks